# How do I assign an object type dynamically?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to loop through all of the controls in a panel. Some of the controls as classes that I created. In those classes, I want a subroutine run when the object is removed. So I am trying to create a temporary object that I can use to run that routine.

```
For Each window As Control In main_window.Controls
  If window.Handle = hdl Then
     Dim temp_window as window.getType()
     temp_window.close_me()
     main_window.Controls.Remove(window)
  End If
Next
```

However, the getType assignment is not allowed.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What is `close_me()`?

Comment: It is the subroutine I want to run for the classes that I created. It does some clean up work before the control is removed. It is set to "Public Shared Sub close_me()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to use a base class that your controls `Inherit` or an interface that your controls `Implement` with `close_me` on the base or interface.  Then, you can `TryCast` each member of `Controls` to the base or interface and, if it succeeds, call `close_me` on it.  If you use the base class approach, you may wish to make it abstract (`MustInherit`) and then `close_me` would be `MustOverride`, depending on if the behavior should be different in each derived type.

e.g. assuming you use `ICloseable`,

```
Interface ICloseable
    Sub close_me()
End Interface

'...

For Each window As Control In main_window.Controls
    If window.Handle = hdl Then
        Dim asCloseable = TryCast(window, ICloseable)
        If asCloseable IsNot Nothing Then
            asCloseable.close_me()
        EndIf
    EndIf
Next
```

Comment: This sounds like it will work, but I'm getting "Type ICloseable is not defined." Where do I define that? My classes inherit Panel as a base type.

Comment: I set my class to inherit Panel and then I implement ICloneable in the class. Changing the above code to ICloneable instead of ICloseable works for my purpose. Thanks.

Comment: @user2721815 If `ICloneable` has the method that you want, then that's fine.  But if you really want `close_me` then you need to create your own interface that your controls would also implement.

Comment: How do I do that? How do I create my own interface?

Comment: @user2721815 see my updated answer.  It can go into any class file; I will usually either put it in its own source file, or put it in the source file along with the primary implementation of the interface.  To use the interface on a class, add e.g. `Implements ICloseable` either as the first line under the `Class MyClass` line, or immediately after any other `Implements` or `Inherits` lines.  Visual Studio will by default add stub methods for interface members which you can edit as desired.

Comment: Now, my trycast (window. ICloseable) is throwing the same error: "Icloseable is not defined." It seems like I need to use a built in interface for it to be recognized as a valid type. ICloneable worked because it is a built in type, but I'd rather use my own if I can.

Comment: I figured it out. I added ICloseable as a new Interface in my project as its own entity. Now it is recognized as legit. Thanks for teaching this to me.

Answer (score 1):

[`Object.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) is not what you want, it returns the `Type` instance of the object which contains meta data of that type, normally used for reflection.

What is the actual type that you want? It has to have a `close_me` method. You could use [`OfType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim windowsToClose = main_window.Controls.OfType(Of YourWindowType)().
    Where(Function(w) w.Handle = hdl).
    ToArray()

For Each window In windowsToClose 
    window.close_me()
    main_window.Controls.Remove(window)
Next
```

Your `For Each` doesn't work for another reason: you can't remove items from the collection while you are enumerating it. Above approach stores the windows you want to remove in an array.

Comment: But not all of the controls are of the same type. So I won't know which type the object is so I wont know how to assign it unless I iterate through all of the possible types.

Comment: Then those controls should implement the same interface(f.e. IClosable) with at least one method close_me

Comment: The problem is that I will have to specifically assign a type using the method above. For example the (Of YourWindowType) will need to be (Of User_page) or (Of Admin_page). I will have many types and I don't want to have to test for each one. I simply want to know what type the control is and then assign that same type to a variable that I can use to call the subroutine with.

Comment: You can't call a method if you don't know the type. You can use If TypeOf window Is User_Page Then... Now you can cast it to that type and use its methods

Comment: That's my problem, I need to get the type so I can assign it to another variable dynamically. So I need something like getType() that will tell me what class was used for that control so I can assign that same class to the new variable without have to test for all of my classes. I don't want 20 if.. then statements and I will be adding more classes in the future so I don't want to have to go back and change my if then choices.

Comment: @user2721815 The right way to do this is using the class or interface system to do dynamic dispatch---that's how you avoid having 20 if...then statements.  If you need to use GetType() to control an assignment, then I would recommend to give some further thought to your design to identify the common elements that would let you work with an interface or base class.